# How to count down in for loop?

Tags: python

In Java, I have the following for loop and I am learning Python:

```
for (int index = last-1; index >= posn; index--)
```

My question is simple and probably obvious for most of people who are familiar with Python. I would like to code that 'for' loop in Python. How can I do this?

I tried to do the following:

```
for index in range(last-1, posn, -1):
```

I think it should be `range(last-1, posn + 1, -1)`. Am I right?

I am thankful to anyone especially who will explain to me how to understand the indices work in Python.

Comment: It says `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: as an aside: depending on what your doing you may prefer enumerate: `for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(list_here))):` where i would count from last element and e would be the actual elements

Comment: @Jika So look at the indices generated by range. Then fix your code.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The range function in python has the syntax:

`range(start, end, step)`

It has the same syntax as python lists where the start is inclusive but the end is exclusive.

So if you want to count from 5 to 1, you would use `range(5,0,-1)` and if you wanted to count from `last` to `posn` you would use `range(last, posn - 1, -1)`.

Comment: And just to be sure, this -1 is because it's stepping backwards from 10 to 0?

Comment: @timman Correct. If you wanted to step backwards from 10 to 5 for instance, it would be `range(10, 4, -1)`.

Answer (score 19):

In python, when you have an iterable, usually you iterate without an index:

```
letters = 'abcdef' # or a list, tupple or other iterable
for l in letters:
    print(l)
```

If you need to traverse the iterable in reverse order, you would do:

```
for l in letters[::-1]:
    print(l)
```

When for any reason you need the index, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for i, l in enumerate(letters, start=1): #start is 0 by default
    print(i,l)
```

You can enumerate in reverse order too...

```
for i, l in enumerate(letters[::-1])
    print(i,l)
```

ON ANOTHER NOTE...

Usually when we traverse an iterable we do it to apply the same procedure or function to each element. In these cases, it is better to use `map`:

If we need to capitilize each letter:

```
map(str.upper, letters)
```

Or get the Unicode code of each letter:

```
map(ord, letters)
```

Comment: Not related to the question. It's about counting down, not traversing a string in reverse, neither enumerating a string.

Answer (score 8):

First I recommand you can try use print and observe the action:

```
for i in range(0, 5, 1):
    print i
```

the result:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

You can understand the function principle.
In fact, `range` scan range is from `0` to `5-1`.
It equals `0 <= i < 5`

When you really understand for-loop in python, I think its time we get back to business. Let's focus your problem.

You want to use a DECREMENT for-loop in python.
I suggest a for-loop tutorial for example.

```
for i in range(5, 0, -1):
    print i
```

the result:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Thus it can be seen, it equals `5 >= i > 0`

You want to implement your java code in python:

```
for (int index = last-1; index >= posn; index--)
```

It should code this:

```
for i in range(last-1, posn-1, -1)
```

Answer (score -4):

If you google. "Count down for loop python" you get these, which are pretty accurate.

[how to loop down in python list (countdown)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620106/how-to-loop-down-in-python-list-countdown)
[Loop backwards using indices in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869885/loop-backwards-using-indices-in-python)

I recommend doing minor searches before posting. Also "Learn Python The Hard Way" is a good place to start.